# How to search for a hidden file in Mac OS?

Tags: spotlight, wine

I need to find a Wine .exe file (winefile.exe) I just installed, but I don`t know where it is, so, besides showing hidden files, I need to find the specific file.
Thanks for help.

Comment: Why is this file hidden? Did you open spotlight and type name:winefile.exe and press enter? It’s not at all clear why spotlight won’t show this file based on date, name or many other items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever reason, on my system, **Spotlight** does not find all **.exe** files. Using, separately, **.exe** or **exe** it only finds some files. Using **filename.exe** it does find it.

As an alternative, you can use the `find` *command* from **Terminal** to find any *file* you want, e.g.:

```
find . -type f -iname '*.exe'
```

In the `find` *command* above `.` is the **PWD**, which by default is your *home directory*.

You can read the *manual page* for `find` in **Terminal** by typing `find` and then right-click on it and select: **Open man Page**

If you prefer not to use **Terminal**, the is a freeware **GUI** app called [**EasyFind**](https://www.devontechnologies.com/apps/freeware).

<sub>Note: I am not affiliated with the developer of **EasyFind**</sub>